# fx.slide on load?

Tags: jquery

Im a little stuck with fx.slide, im trying to run it on page load event. Is there a way to do that?

click event is this

```
var myHorizontalSlide = new Fx.Slide('wrapper', {mode: 'horizontal'});
$('.href').addEvent('click', function(e){
    e.stop();
    myHorizontalSlide.slideOut();
});
```

Comment: `im trying to run it on page load event` ? why, what's currently happening?

Comment: im not certain on how to do it, ive tried changing click to load, taking it out as well as doing .load instead of addEvent

Answer (score 0):

What is it not doing?

You might consider putting your code in;

```
$(document).ready(function (){
//Your code here
})
```